# Ingress controller's load balancer address - Could not resolve host

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

I'm using Nginx ingress controller in kubernetes cluster and its host address (load balancer DNS name) is returning "Could not resolve host: ..".
In AWS, I don't even have load balancer with this DNS name.
However, when I run kubectl logs on ingress controller, it's still receiving traffic normally. 
**How is it possible for ingress controller to have a host that can't be found and still receives traffic?**

**Nginx Ingress Controller service**

```
-> kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe svc ingress-nginx-controller
   ...
   LoadBalancer Ingress: xxx.elb.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com #deprecated
   Port:                     http  80/TCP
   TargetPort:               http/TCP
   NodePort:                 http  31610/TCP
   Endpoints:                10.0.51.53:80
   Port:                     https  443/TCP
   TargetPort:               http/TCP
   NodePort:                 https  32544/TCP
   Endpoints:                10.0.51.53:80
   Session Affinity:         None
   External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
   Events:
   Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  32m (x6919 over 24d)  service-controller (combined from similar events): Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: error creating load balancer listener: "TargetGroupAssociationLimit:
   The following target groups cannot be associated with more than one load balancer: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-northeast-2:4xxx:targetgroup/k8s-ingressn-ingressn-5f8ebc7e16/25aa0ef278298505\n\tstatus
   code: 400, request id: d1767330-f7d1-4c4f-bcf1-4f1e4af8ab9f"   
   Normal 
   EnsuringLoadBalancer    2m40s (x6934 over 24d)  service-controller Ensuring load balancer

-> curl  xxx.elb.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xxx.elb.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com
```

**Ingress using deprecated DNS**

```
-> kubectl describe ingress slack-api-ingress
   Name:             slack-api-ingress
   Namespace:        default
   Address:          xxx.elb.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com #deprecated
   Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
   ...
```

I have another NLB in AWS which was initially provisioned by ingress controller and I can still access my services with this lb's DNS name.
I'm assuming that ingress controller tried to update and create a new load balancer, but still directs traffic to previous lb after failing to create new lb.  If this is the case, I want ingress-controller to use previous lb's DNS.
I'm new to kubernetes and probably don't know what's going on so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use EKS?

Comment: Yes, I'm using EKS.
I managed to change the Ingress controller's host address by detaching target groups from previous NLB and allow Ingress controller to create a new NLB with existing target groups. I'm assuming ingress controller's host address is not important but setting the right target groups matter.